# JAVA 8 - Change compiler to Java 8 instead of Java 6

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So I have an issue that I could not change my compiler in IntelliJ. 
I am going to Preferences»Build, Execution, Development»Java Compiler

After I change Java 1.8 - 
Then I run my code and it is popping out a debug info:

"java 6 used to compile java sources"

After two:       " invalid source release 1.8 " 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTo0f.png)

---- Mac OS X - installed JAVA SE kit ---

May I have to change my compiler in terminal ?

What should I wrote there  ?

Can anybody help, because without it I can't even run my code.. : (

Comment: ***Mentioning
 If I write in terminal Java -version, it will put out '1.8'
but inside IntelliJ-idea it is used by 1.6 

How can I force to change inside IntelliJ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to set project SDK in Intellij](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31506278/unable-to-set-project-sdk-in-intellij)

Comment: Try File > Project Structure > Project > Project SDK

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the project settings are overriding your global IntelliJ preferences. Try changing the SDK version in project structure.

In the latest version of IntelliJ I found this in:

```
File > Project Structure > Project tab > Project SDK
```

Comment: Yep. 
If I get out SDK, it will star using 1.8. 


And there I see it uses 6 instead of 8. 





Thank you!

Comment: But now. It works - ok. It uses 1.8 then, I got this message:

 source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8 

Which actually the same. 

One thing more!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888592/errorjava-javactask-source-release-8-requires-target-release-1-8